# Registro de usuarios PYTHON

Tags: python, lista, programación-bajo-nivel, cuenta-usuario

Tengo un problema, con este registro de usuarios que hice, supuestamente tengo que hacer un registro de usuarios donde imprima la lista de usuarios con su contraseña en un archivo en el drive, pero cuando lo hago, me guarda solamente el ultimo usuario que ingrese, los anteriores se borran, tienen alguna idea?
Gracias

```
lista = list()

class Alumnos:
  def __init__(self):
    self.usuario =(" ")
    self.contraseña =( )

def menu():
  seleccion=0
  while seleccion != 3:
    print("1. registrar alumno")
    print("2. ver alumnos registrados")
    print("3. salir")
    seleccion = int(input("Elija una opcion: "))
    if seleccion == 1:
      registrar()
    if seleccion == 2:
      mostrar()
    if seleccion == 3:
      salir()
      
def registrar():
  print("Funcion para registrar alumnos")
  alumno=Alumnos()
  alumno.usuario=input("Introduce tu nombre: ")
  alumno.contraseña=input("Introduce tu contraseña: ")
  lista.append(alumno)

def mostrar():
  print("Ver el registro de alumnos")
  for alumno in lista:
    print("El alumno",alumno.usuario,"tiene de contraseña",alumno.contraseña)

  d = {"USUARIO": alumno.usuario, "CONTRASEÑA": alumno.contraseña}

  ruta_archivo = ruta + "/usuarios_archivo.txt" 
  f = open(ruta_archivo, "w")


  contenido_del_archivo = f"{d['USUARIO']},{d['CONTRASEÑA']}"
  f.write (contenido_del_archivo)

  f.close()

def salir():
  print("Gracias por registrarte")

#--------------------------------------------------
menu()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón es que no estas grabando cada alumno en el ciclo `for`, solo los imprimes. Luego que termina el ciclo, grabas el archivo con lo último alumno procesado.

Debes mover la grabación junto con la impresión. También debes usar `with` para abrir el archivo (y se cierra solo):

```
ruta = '.'
def mostrar():
    print("Ver el registro de alumnos")

    ruta_archivo = ruta + "/usuarios_archivo.txt"

    with open(ruta_archivo, "w") as f:
        for alumno in lista:
            print("El alumno", alumno.usuario, "tiene de contraseña", alumno.contraseña)
            f.write(f"{alumno.usuario}, {alumno.contraseña}\n")
```

#### Demo

```
1. registrar alumno
2. ver alumnos registrados
3. salir
Elija una opcion: 1
Funcion para registrar alumnos
Introduce tu nombre: andres
Introduce tu contraseña: kkadf
1. registrar alumno
2. ver alumnos registrados
3. salir
Elija una opcion: 1
Funcion para registrar alumnos
Introduce tu nombre: raul
Introduce tu contraseña: 1232
1. registrar alumno
2. ver alumnos registrados
3. salir
Elija una opcion: 2
Ver el registro de alumnos
El alumno andres tiene de contraseña kkadf
El alumno raul tiene de contraseña 1232
```

y el archivo generado:

```
gabriel@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$ more usuarios_archivo.txt 
andres, kkadf
raul, 1232
```